# Reputation points discrepancy in Android app

Tags: bug, reputation, android-app

I just noticed that reputation points reported in the Android app profile section differs from what is reported when you provide an answer. In my case it's by 15 points.

- App Version: 1.0.94
- Android Nexus-6
- OS Version: 7.1.2 (eng.nate.20170423.191744)
- Forum: StackOverflow

Comment: Caching, always caching.

Comment: It's been like that for over 24 hours.

Comment: Is it showing the stale reputation on the top row in "More", or when you click on that row to view your profile, or both?

Comment: It cleared up a few hours after my previous post (so about 24 - 36 hours stale). Points in signatures to posted answers were okay. The stale part was seen when tapping the Drawer section of the Android App, and then tapping the profile name to see information. That is where the points was incorrect.

Comment: @prismalytics.io ah got it, that's supposed to get updated periodically (and each time we think your rep has changed, e.g. when you get new achievements) -- I think i need to reduce the time delay in its update, or move it over to something that automatically updates faster if the phone is on WiFi/charging.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Thank you for elaborating.